# How to set custom Order by in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, substring, customization

I have the following query:

```
select distinct CustomerID, SortOrder, Seq
from #result
Order By CASE 
    WHEN Substring(SortOrder, 0, 1) = '~' THEN 9999999 
    else SortOrder 
    END
```

However, I get the following error message: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

How could I go about creating this custom order by the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `group by` instead:

```
select CustomerID, SortOrder, Seq
from #result
group by CustomerID, SortOrder, Seq
Order By (CASE WHEN Substring(SortOrder, 0, 1) = '~' THEN 9999999 
               else SortOrder 
          END);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting the extra column, then simply include your case statement in the result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    CustomerID,  
    SortOrder,  
    CASE  
    WHEN Substring(SortOrder, 0, 1) = '~' THEN 9999999  
    ELSE SortOrder  
    END 
FROM 
    #result 
ORDER BY  
    CASE  
    WHEN Substring(SortOrder, 0, 1) = '~' THEN 9999999  
    ELSE SortOrder  
    END
```